# What could be causing my Elementor editing interface to only show text instead of images on my new template?

Tags: elementor, image-editing

I have installed a new template on my website, and it seems to be displaying correctly. However, I am facing a problem when trying to edit it with Elementor. The editing interface is not fully displayed, showing only the text.

I am trying to edit a new template using Elementor, but the template doesn't display the images, only the text